# How to show user information in angularJS frontend with Passport and nodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, passport.js

Im trying to replicate this local authentication with [the passport tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local).

but with an angularJS frontend instead of EJS, until now everything works, but I have a problem when I want to show the user data in the profile page (after a successful login)

I'm talking about this piece of code

```
 // =====================================
    // PROFILE SECTION =====================
    // =====================================
    // we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
    // we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });
```

I understand that user is the data that I need, but in the example with EJS is used like this:

```
<!-- LOCAL INFORMATION -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well">
                <h3><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Local</h3>

                    <p>
                        <strong>id</strong>: <%= user._id %><br>
                        <strong>email</strong>: <%= user.local.email %><br>
                        <strong>password</strong>: <%= user.local.password %>
                    </p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Can I access this same data with AngularJS? I'm a bit new in this and I don't understand how

Comment: +1 for the link to the nice tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the data in Angular as well. Hope you have bootstraped your angular application. Use this:

#### Local

```
                <p>
                    <strong>id</strong>: {{user._id}}<br>
                    <strong>email</strong>: {{user.local.email}}<br>
                    <strong>password</strong>: {{user.local.password}}
                </p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This 'user' will use the scope variable which you will define in your controller

**Controller Function**

```
function test($scope) {
    $scope.user = user; //Need to get this user from the server call (by $http or a service)
}
```

Comment: something like this? 


     $http.get('/profile')
     .success(function(data) {
   $scope.user = user;

Comment: absolutely however I would advice to create a factory rather than have $http call in the controller itself

Comment: Any luck @user3877179?

Comment: what do you mean with bootstrap your app? maybe i need that

Comment: you need to initialize the app with ng-app and state the name of the module if any....can you create a jsfiddle of your client code so that we can help you better

Comment: Here is the code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gary_raya/X6S28/1/) i put my angular code in the html space, pls try to help me, this is driving me crazy =(, maybe the is the rs.render that i changed for res.sendfile...

Comment: First the controller is defined incorrectly it should be moduloAngular.controller('controlador',function($scope, $http) {,

Comment: still not working , i will keep looking for the fix, do you see any more problems? thanks